# grails, java - Using ECMAScript 6 unicode code point escapes in message.properties

Tags: java, grails, unicode, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain to me why it is possible to use usual unicode escape squences like `\u0043` in the message.properties file of grails but not the ECMAScript 6 unicode code point escapes like `\u{1F60A}`.

If I try to use the latter I get the following error message: `Malformed \uxxxx encoding`. Removing the `{}` does not help either because then only the first four hex digits are interpreted.

A possible workaround is to use the corresponding surrogate pair - `\uD83D\uDE0A` in this case.

Nevertheless, it would be much easier to be able to use the original unicode code point in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have here is that Java as a language says that property files support Unicode escapes as (defined in [section 3.3 of The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)) the ASCII characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits.

Plain and simple. That's the language specification. Not ECMAScript 6.